# SideMenuController not working on some views

Tags: ios, swift

I am using [SideMenuController](https://github.com/teodorpatras/SideMenuController), and the menu works only in some views. The "menu" button is clickable in all views, but the side menu appears only in some views. Is there any specific reason for this? Have I missed something?

Comment: use this, https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift

Comment: try this https://github.com/ashishkakkad8/AKSwiftSlideMenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `self.navigationController?.addSideMenuButton()` to the required `ViewController` did it.